# Plugins that restrict access based on user group/roles

Tags: user-access

I'm quite shocked to learn that out of all the Restrict Access plugins for WordPress, there's not one I can find that suits my needs. Basically I have two requirements: Do not display the page in wp_list_pages and Do not display the page in search results.

I tried 7 plugins: Members, Advanced Access Manager, Restrict Content, Page Security, Maven Member, User Access Manager, and WordPress Access Control.

Advanced Access Manager was the only plugin that restricted the page from being displayed on the wp_list_pages. WordPress Access Control is the only plugin that explicitly addressed the search issue.

Am I going to have to use 2 plugins to meet my requirements?

Answer (score 1):

Try [Role scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin too.

Comment: horrible UI, complicated and eats up screenspace...I don't think this will suit my client's needs

Comment: If you cleaner UI then you should buy their premium plugin. [Check this site](http://presspermit.com)  PS:Press Permit is a
content permissions plugin
for WordPress, from the creator of Role Scoper.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this article](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/daily-tip-new-wordpress-cms-tool-to-restrict-access-based-on-user-roles/) WordPress Access Control should support suppressing pages from WordPress' Page List as well:

> Restricted pages added to the navigation menu will not appear to users
>   without the correct permissions. It fully supports wp_nav_menu,
>   wp_page_menu, and wp_list_pages.

So you should not need two plugins (anymore).